# Sed back referencing with Extended Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, bash, url, sed

I'm writing a `sed` script that tries to make some modifications into a bunch of XML's which contain sensitive information such as URL and IP addresses.

I'm aware that ERE (aka Extended Regular Expressions) do not implement the BRE back-references, e.g. `\(...\)`.

Since ERE provide useful shortcuts `(?,+)` as well as many other benefits, Is there any way to use the *n-th* sub-match of the left-side re in the substitution pattern of `sed`?

A minimal example of this (with BRE) could be like:

```
sed -e 's|\(www[0-9]*\.\)[a-zA-Z0-9._]*\(\.domain\.com[a-zA-Z0-9._/]*\)|\1subtituted_text.\2|g' <large.xml >filtered.xml
```

Assuming an XML with content

```
<name>www12.subdomain2.subdomain1.subdomain0.domain.com/ssl/ca-crt</name>
```

I would like to transform it into:

```
<name>www12.substituted_text.domain.com/ssl/ca-crt</name>
```

Comment: Please show some sample input and desired output, together with the problem you are facing. Now it is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back-referencing in BRE: `\(pattern\)` makes the sub-pattern and access with `\n`
Back-referencing in ERE: `(pattern)`makes the sub-pattern and access with `\n`

Your sed command in ERE:

```
sed -r 's#(www[0-9]*\.)[a-zA-Z0-9._]*(\.domain\.com[a-zA-Z0-9._/]*)#\1subtituted_text.\2#g'
```